# Simple HTML Dom Crawler returns more than contained in attributes

Tags: php, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

I would like to extract the contents contained within certain parts of a website using selectors. I am using Simple HTML DOM to do this. However for some reason more data is returned than present in the selectors that I specify. I have checked the [FAQ of Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm), but did not see anything that could help me out. I wasn't able to find anything on Stackoverflow either.

I am trying to get the contents/hrefs of all *h2 class="hed"* tags contained within the *ul class="river"* on this webpage: http://www.theatlantic.com/most-popular/

In my output I am receiving a lot of data from other tags like *p class="dek has-dek"* that are not contained within the h2 tag and should not be included. This is really strange as I thought the code would only allow for content within those tags to be scraped.

How can I limit the output to only include the data contained within the h2 tag?

**Here is the code I am using:**

```
<div class='rcorners1'>
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$target_url = "http://www.theatlantic.com/most-popular/";

$html = new simple_html_dom();

$html->load_file($target_url);

$posts = $html->find('ul[class=river]');
$limit = 10;
$limit = count($posts) < $limit ? count($posts) : $limit;
for($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++){
  $post = $posts[$i];
  $post->find('h2[class=hed]',0)->outertext = "";
  echo strip_tags($post, '<p><a>');
  }
  ?>
  </div>
```

[Output can be seen here](http://globalsocialnews.com/crawler/test8.php). Instead of only a couple of article links, I get information of the author, information on the article, among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not outputting the `h2` contents, but the `ul` contents in the `echo`:

```php
echo strip_tags($post, '<p><a>');
```

Note that the statement before the `echo` does not modify *$post*:

```php
$post->find('h2[class=hed]',0)->outertext = "";
```

Change code to this:

```php
$hed = $post->find('h2[class=hed]',0);
echo strip_tags($hed, '<p><a>');
```

However, that will only do something with the first found `h2`. So you need another loop. Here is a rewrite of the code after `load_file`:

```php
$posts = $html->find('ul[class=river]');
foreach($posts as $postNum => $post) {
    if ($postNum >= 10) break; // limit reached
    $heds = $post->find('h2[class=hed]');
    foreach($heds as $hed) {
        echo strip_tags($hed, '<p><a>');
    }
}
```

If you still need to clear `outertext`, you can do it with *$hed*:

```php
$hed->outertext = "";
```

Comment: Hi trincot, I tried this and it works partially, but now I only get a single article title instead of all of them. I switched out  $post->find('h2[class=hed]',0)->outertext = "";
  echo strip_tags($post, '<p><a>'); with your code, was that correct?

Comment: Yes, that was correct. I have updated my answer with a loop on `h2` tags. Because I saw the 0 in `find('h2[class=hed]',0)` I thought you were not interested in other `h2` tags, but apparently you are ;-)

Comment: Thank you! At the risk of losing your patience, I have a follow-up question. I want the links as well, so I am now finding `$heds = $post->find('a[data-omni-click=inherit]');`- this gives me an unwanted attribute though _<figure>_. I would like to exclude it from the output, so I tried `$heds = $post->find('a[data-omni-click=inherit]', '!figure');` after I found that you can exclude attributes with an exclamation mark [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find). This did not work though. Do you know how to exclude an attribute? Would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You really only need one loop. Consider this:

```
foreach($html->find('ul.river > h2.hed') as $postNum => $h2) {
  if ($postNum >= 10) break;
  echo strip_tags($h2, '<p><a>') . "\n"; // the text
  echo $h2->parent->href . "\n"; // the href
}
```